# Dart dynamic generic type check, type not inferred in below scope

Tags: dart

I do not understand why in the snippet below commented line does not infer the state as `SubState<dynamic>`.

```dart
class Commander<T> {
  final State<T> state;

  Commander(this.state);
  void doSomething() {
    final state = this.state;
    if (state is SubState) {
      // print(state.property); // Does not work.
    }
  }
  
  void doOther() {
    final state = this.state;
    if (state is SubState<T>) {
      print(state.property); // This works.
    }
  }
}

abstract class State<T> {}

class SubState<T> extends State<T> {
  T property;
  SubState(this.property);
}
```

Comment: That `state is SubState` does not promotes the local `state` variable to `SubState<dynamic>` smells like a bug to me. (An explicit `state is SubState<dynamic>` check does not work either.) You probably should [file an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues).

Comment: This is https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34018 (which I probably should have remembered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only promote a variable to a subtype of its declared type.

The (inferred) declared type of the local `state` variable is `State<T>`.
You then does an `is` test with `SubState`, aka. `SubState<dynamic>`.
Since `SubState<dynamic>` is not a subtype of `State<T>`, it doesn't promote.
Doing `is SubState<T>` is checking and promoting to a subtype.

(And as @jamesdlin points out, this is a known short-coming of type inference, where it would probably be better if the raw `SubState` type didn't automatically mean `SubState<dynamic>`.)

Comment: it would be more practical to mean SubState<WhateverTIsOnTheLeftOfIs>